# Input Defaulting to String in Python 3.x Even if Numbers are Entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a total noob, so thank you for your patience.  I'm having trouble accepting integer inputs in my program; they all come out as strings.  I confirmed this by adding the type() lines that are currently commented out.  How do I make my program accept inputs as integers?  Thanks.

```
# TIP CALCULATOR


def main():

    cost = input('Please enter the cost of your meal or service.')
    tip_percentage = input('Please enter what percentage of tip you would like to pay.')
    #print(type(cost))
    #print(type(tip_percentage))
    total = tip_percentage * cost + cost
    return total


final = main()
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input()` function reads the input from `stdin` which is actually a file object and return a string. If you want to have your input in integer type you can use `int()` function for convert the string digits to integer. But note that you should wrap it with a `try-except` expression in order to handle the `ValueError`, if user inputs something except digit.

```
try:
    tip_percentage = input('Please enter what percentage of tip you would like to pay.')
except ValueError: 
    tip_percentage = input('Please enter a valid digit')
else:
    # do something with tip_percentage
```

And if you want to do this until user inputs a valid integer you can put the preceding snippet in a while loop with condition True, and break the loop in `else` section.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to a int:

```
cost = int(input('Please enter the cost of your meal or service.'))
```